# CASE statement with IS NULL and NOT NULL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there any better way to write the lines below in SQL Server 2005?

```
CASE
WHEN (ID IS NULL)
   THEN 'YES'
WHEN (ID IS NOT NULL)
   THEN 'NO'
END AS ID_Value,
```

Comment: Define "better".

Comment: I'm not familiar with MSSQL but if it has something like IF-function in MySQL, you can write such code: `IF(ID IS NULL, 'YES', 'NO') AS ID_Value`

Comment: SQL Server 2012 has [`IIF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) but the question is tagged 2005.

Comment: You should be able to accomplish this with the statement below. `isnull(nullif(isnull(ID,'Y'),ID),'N')`

Comment: @Jason Assuming `ID` is a string, of course. Otherwise this expression should be elongated a little more by a call to `CAST` or `CONVERT`.

Comment: Tried using `COALESCE`? `CASE COALESCE(ID,0) WHEN 0 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END`

Comment: @Bappy1988 Why would it be better than Jay's answer?

Comment: This does not work if the column in the test is of IMAGE datatype. SQL Server throws the following error: "The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator."

Comment: You are looking for something like the ?: operator in C# and there is no direct equivalent in tsql  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx  I suspect you could write a function to do it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx

Answer (score 18):

Did you try:

```
CASE WHEN (ID IS NULL) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS ID_Value,
```

I only have access to 2008 right now, but I'd hope that this syntax would still work in 2005 (*seems* like something that would be part of the original definition of `CASE`).

Comment: Yes - I did try `CASE WHEN (ID IS NULL) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS ID_Value` But I am looking for some other better approach something like `IF(ID IS NULL, 'YES', 'NO') AS ID_Value` in the Ms Sql, so that everything can be in a single line. Any suggestions please

Comment: This answer is in a single line. If you want you can put the whole statement in a single line.